# Report rdlc - Shrink rectangle inside tablix in group

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I have a .rdlc report with grouping (4 levels).

In the last level, I have a pretty complex design of textboxes/images that can't be done with rows/cols. For example, they overlap on some points.
So what I have to do is to put a Rectangle on the cell and then, inside the Rectangle, put all the components.

The problem I have now is that some of these components can be hidden depending on the data, and because of that, sometimes there is a lot of white space inside the report that I don't want.

Is there any way to shrink the Rectangle if it doesn't have any visible data?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, by design [Rows and Columns will not shrink below its definition height/width](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2008/10/09/canshrink-does-not-work-with-rdlc-when-the-textbox-is-within-a-data-control-like-table-matrix/), therefore, a Rectangle can only be as small as its Cell.

However, you could try to make it as small as possible, and rely on the CanGrow property of Textboxes ("Property" window, under "General" tab), as suggested in the link given above.

Comment: I can't make the cell any smaller as I have to put the textBoxes in exact positions and over a background image that is the base of the data. Imagine the image is something like a architectural plan and the dynamic data is the sizes